# Yocto minimal image failed

Tags: yocto

I am trying to build "core-image-minimal" in centos 7. 
How to fix this error.

## bitbake core-image-minimal

```
    fatal: repository '/my_data/yocto/poky/build/downloads/git2/git.yoctoproject.org.linux-yocto.git/' does not exist

ERROR: linux-yocto-4.18.21+gitAUTOINC+8f4a98c938_9eddc793f9-r0 do_unpack: Function failed: base_do_unpack
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /my_data/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/qemux86-poky-linux/linux-yocto/4.18.21+gitAUTOINC+8f4a98c938_9eddc793f9-r0/temp/log.do_unpack.22789
ERROR: Task (/my_data/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto_4.18.bb:do_unpack) failed with exit code '1'
```

Comment: show us the command you're running, your `local.conf` and `bblayers.conf`. it looks like you're trying to git clone kernel from the local folder that does not exist.

Comment: It worked after I removed poky directory contents and re-downloaded it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the **tmp/** dir and building from scratch again works for me.